# PHP IF statement with 2 conditions

Tags: javascript, php

I have this issue where I am trying to check my variables.

So I have a form. The user click on send.
The variable is sent using a post with

```
xhr.open("POST", "ajax_http.php?", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.send(sVar4);
```

This is working good my variables are being sent to ajax_http.php

Now when I try to check my variables i use php and do the following :

```
 $stuff = $_POST['stuff'];

 if(isset($stuff) && (strlen($stuff) > 200)){
   $var = $stuff;   
 } else{
   $error = true;
 }
```

So first thing I noticed is that my variable  `$_POST['stuff']` is always set even if it's empty. And no matter the length of the `strlen($stuff)` my `$var` always get set and `$error` never get set to true.

I believe my `if()` statement is wrong but what is wrong.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You typed the var as $tuff and not $stuff

Comment: Does your code actually have `strlen($tuff)`? If so, do you have another variable `$tuff` with length over 200? That would explain the behavior.

Comment: I think it should be && strlen($tuff) not $$ ( strlen($tuff)

Comment: You have  typo $tuff instead of $stuff for you variable parameter in strlen()

Comment: No thats not it unfortunatly that was just a type when i wrote the question and i did verify my code.

Comment: Maybe its because you  are saying `if  isset($stuff) is true or is defined then do this`

Comment: Well i just found out that is was actualy working. The problem was from the way i check for errors with if($error != 0)

Comment: if($error !== 0) is working

Comment: obligatory you should escape the contents of `$_POST` with `htmlspecialchars`

Comment: Thank you guys thats working now. i guess i should sleep a bit (=

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is a more accurate way or checking if your value is set.

```
if(isset($_POST['stuff']))
{
    $stuff = $_POST['stuff'];
    //echo $stuff . "<br>";
    //echo strlen($stuff); to see its contents to help understand why it wont run the $var = $stuff; statement
    if((strlen($stuff) > 200))
    {
      $var = $stuff;             
    }
    else
    {
       $error = true;
    }
}
else
{
    //Do whatever necessary :)
}
```

Comment: This is the same code though isnt it? The issue is that it is always set but sometimes empty

Comment: Well, the issue is that with the original code, you check if $stuff is set or not AND you check its strlen. Technically, if $stuff is not set, the strlen check is useless. With the example i provided, the strlen check will not even execute if $_POST['stuff'] is not set or null. I have to agree that empty() would be more accurate for the current goal, but still I believe the order of checks matter, just print the value before each if statementto check the values.

Answer (score 1):

You could use empty() since your concern is that it is set even if it is empty. Only proceed if it is not empty.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

```
if(!empty($stuff) && strlen($stuff) > 200){
//do stuff
}
```